# For loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My current code:

```
Sub test()
    aaa = InputBox("which objects do you want to keep, ie some on the screen:")

    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabell").UsedRange

    For Each cell In myrange.Cells
        If Not (cell.Value Like aaa & "*") Then
            cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But the problem with it is that you can write in once what it should keep. That is, the user can only enter once and then it will delete everything except what it writes.

But I want the user to be able to type in several times before removing everything else. That is, I want the user to write, for example: Objects, Coler, Längd (AND SEN if it writes the word END then the program should end up asking him), If he wants to write several things.

So I want the user to be able to write several things and then when he is finished writing END and then it stops asking him. Can you help me to do one (For loop) that will enable the user to enter several things. And then (For the loop) ends when the user enters END

Comment: Research how to use filters: [Filter data in a range or table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). This should be much easier.

Comment: Hi thanks for your tip.
But I'd rather have a VBA code for this. Please help me

Comment: I had started modifying my answer because I hand't understood the test case. I thought you wanted to remove the values in input, not keep them, so my code was removing them instead of keeping them. Then I've read your comment and didn't like the tone, so I've opted to delete the answer at all, good luck with your research. Good thing is you at least have the first part for the loop now, you can update your question so next helper will just have to take care of the second part ;)

Comment: Hi Matteo!

Excuse me if I said something wrong. I don't mean anything bad. I have just tried to make it work for a long time now but did not succeed.

Please help me.

Excuse me if I was unpleasant.

Comment: I'm just angry that you myself couldn't succeed. I greatly appreciate your help.
But as I said excuse you if I think I was unpleasant, I didn't mean anything bad

Comment: There's no problem don't worry, it might have been me misunderstading the way you were talking to me. I suggest you add the loop I wrote into your question and just make the question all about keeping the values given the collection, it's more concise and you might have more chances to get more help.

Comment: I cannot see the answer that @Matteo NNZ suggested, any more, but it looks like removing Not may be all that is required, as indicated by the first commenter on that answer.

Comment: Here's the answer from him

Comment: Sub test()

    Dim objectsToRemove As New Collection
    Dim currentObject As String

    Do While currentObject <> "END"
        currentObject = InputBox("which objects do you want to keep, ie some on the screen:")
        If currentObject <> "END" Then objectsToRemove.Add currentObject
    Loop

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabell").UsedRange


For Each cell In myrange.Cells

Comment: For Each obj In objectsToRemove '<-- we apply the same logic of yours to each obj inside objectsToRemove
            If Not (cell.Value Like obj & "*") Then
                cell.Value = ""
            End If
        Next obj

Next
End Sub

Comment: @F.Ymn you can use filters with VBA. Start using filters manually and then record a macro doing it manually to see how this works in VBA.

Comment: @niton that was it, I accidentally left the Not inside the loop because I copied-pasted the code and admit I didn't review it properly. But the problem is that OP wants to *keep* the inputs, not *remove* them, so a different loop should be built for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete cells which do not contain one of mutiple specified words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162186/delete-cells-which-do-not-contain-one-of-mutiple-specified-words)