# Delete cells which do not contain one of mutiple specified words

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel code that removes everything that I do not enter.

If a user enters dog, cat, house and then END all cells containing the word dog, cat and house should remain. All other cells should be removed.

Right now, it works if the user writes for example Dog and then END. Then it will remove all cells but where it says Dog. I need it to work if the user writes: Dog, Cat, House and then END

```
Sub test()

    Dim objectsToRemove As New Collection '<-- collection to store all the strings
    Dim currentObject As String

    Do While currentObject <> "END" '<-- while the input is different than "END", we keep on asking inputs
        currentObject = InputBox("which objects do you want to keep, ie some on the screen:")
        If currentObject <> "END" Then objectsToRemove.Add currentObject '<-- and add them to the collection
    Loop

    Dim myrange As Range

    Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabell").UsedRange

    For Each cell In myrange.Cells
        For Each obj In objectsToRemove '<-- we apply the same logic of yours to each obj inside objectsToRemove
            If Not (cell.Value Like obj & "*") Then
                cell.Value = ""
            End If
        Next obj
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code clears the cell as soon as the value does't match one of the strings in the collection. I think I would use a dictionary which has an Exists property. Or you could use autofilter or find.

Comment: The idea is that all words I write so keep it. Example example Dog, cat, house. And all other cells that do not contain (dog, cat house) the words so removed. For example, if it says car, boat mobile on other cells then they should be removed.


Thank you so much for your help. And excuse me if my question is perhaps unclear

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful and descriptive of the problem or question. If you remove the redundant (and therefore unnecessary) tags `vba excel`, it leaves the title `for loop`, which will be of no use to a future reader here who sees it in a list of search results.

Comment: Hi @SJR. Thank you for understanding what I mean. The thing is that I want to have a full VBA code for this. You can help me.

The thing is that my code does not work completely smoothly. Because if you test enter Dog and then ENTER, Cat and then ENTER, House and then ENTER and finally END then it will not work.

But only works if you write Dog and then ENTER and then END.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem you have. Nacorid's answer solves it I think.

Comment: Hi @SJR. Nacorid Help me very much. I'm very thankful for his help. I only have one last wish. Please look at my answer to Nacorid. It is a little further down the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the cell clearing code outside your loop. Use a `boolean` to check if the cell should be cleared:

```
Dim someBool as Boolean ' Should be named something meaningful to you
                        ' to understand the logic 6 months down the line

' Other code

For Each cell In myrange.Cells
    someBool = True
    For Each obj In objectsToRemove ' Should be named objectsToKeep
        If (cell.Value Like "*" & obj & "*") Then
            someBool = False
        End If
    Next obj
    If someBool Then cell.Value = ""
Next
```

Comment: Hi @Nacorid .  Thanks you very much much for your help !


Excuse me for interrupting. I just have one last thing.

Right now everyone is taken away as a user. So if I enter Dog and then Enter, Cat and then Enter, House and then Enter. And then END.
Then all dogs, cats and houses are taken away. I want it to do the other way round. Ie it should keep them. So I want it to remove everyone else. That is, it should remove everything else and not dog, cat and house. in other words, the other way round of what it does now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and excuse me for being the worst at explaining what I mean :)

Comment: Hi :) Thanks so much for your help. Very nice that you took your time to help me.

Comment: If this solved your problem consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to this post and also: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55162186/edit) your post and change your title to something meaningful. As mentioned in another comment, as it stands, other people will not be ablte to find this post while searching the site for similar problems.